# Laravel 7- AWS - Elastic Beanstalk + RDS Error when running "php artisan migrate"

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am trying to run a Laravel Application in Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. 
I am using Laravel Version 7 and PHP 7.4 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. 
Every time when I try to run **"php artisan migrate"** I get this error: 
My database RDS credentials are all correct.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from
>   information_sche                               ma.tables where
>   table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type
>   = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> at
>   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
>       667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll                                format the error
>       668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make th                               is exception a
>       669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the databa                               se's errors.
>       670|         catch (Exception $e) {
>       671|             throw new QueryException(
>       672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>       673|             );
>       674|         }
>       675|

Comment: you cant do that.. RDS will block that query from laravel maybe y you create a permission in the RDS for that... but the easiest way is to run a aws ligthsail and not a beanstalk, that way you will have your code and your db in the same server, thats what i do.

Comment: @Alex Guerrero I edited all Security Groups and opened all ports to all traffic ( for testing purpose ) because I just wanted it to work. But it didn't. So why can I not do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my own question.

I ran in the **/var/www/html** directory via SSH

> php artisan migrate -vv

to get the debug log and the stacktrace of the migration process. 
I noticed that Laravel is not using the Environment variables (DB_HOST etc. ) when running the migration command. 
So I added the **.ebextensions** directory and created a new file: 
**migration.config**

```
container_commands:
     01migrations:
        command: "php artisan migrate"
```

Now the migration is working, because Laravel gets the access to the environment variables.
So even the newest versions Laravel 7, MYSQL 8.0.17 and PHP 7.4 are working on Elastic Beanstalk RDS.

**EDIT:** 
If you have specified in AWS as environment variable:

> APP_ENV = "production"

use `php artisan migrate --force` instead of `php artisan migrate`

Regards
NKol